# Should I close "Does my code work?" questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I feel like this question should be closed as being "Unclear what you're asking".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499588/need-help-troubleshooting-small-amount-of-java-code

Except it is pretty clear what they're asking... they're asking "Does my code work?"

It seems to me that the question is so localized that it'll never be of any use to future readers. But we no longer have the "too localized" closure reason - it was replaced with "Unclear what you're asking", "Too broad", and "Primarily Opinion Based".

Do people agree with me that it should be closed, and if so, does anyone have a suggestion for picking which reason to close it with?

Comment: I'd prefer to downvote it, honestly.  If it's not on the front page the likelihood of it causing harm is lessened.

Comment: I would vote as "off-topic > why doesn't it work". The question to ask the OP is "why _doesn't_ your code work? Does it not perform to your needs?"

Comment: "Unclear" seems reasonable. His title is "Need help troubleshooting..." but then his only comment is "I have Write Just a pseudo code , it is not for Compiling..." which means he doesn't want troubleshooting, he wants advice. On something, possibly OOP fundamentals.

Comment: @gnat: This is not a duplicate - that one is about debugging. The person in my case hasn't even gotten as far as debugging - he isn't sure if his code works.

Comment: if this doesn't feel fit, consider custom reason: ["Unclear What Help You Need..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215806/165773)

Comment: @gnat: That looks perfect - can we get that implemented?

Comment: I wish we could. I for one prefer not to wait until SE team developers evaluate and fit it into their schedule - I simply put it into "personalized reason" box shown to 3K users under Closing > Off-Topic -> Other

Comment: Doesn't it just belong on another Stack Exchange site ([Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)), therefore it is off-topic?

Comment: @Pluto: Being on-topic somewhere else does not make it off-topic here.

Comment: As an aside, despite its title, all moderation actions are considered in the question I just dupe-closed with...

Comment: Yes, you should vote to close because it's "gimme teh test cases." It's the OP's responsibility to test their code, not ours.