# Reacting to do-it-for-me questions

Tags: discussion, questions

As my question's title is self-descriptive, what should I do for reacting to "do it for me" questions? Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861629/remove-data-between-two-values-sql).

Answer or Downvote ?

Comment: downvote. please downvote. please don't answer and make it look like we're a code writing service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What close reason should I use for give me teh codez?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253137/what-close-reason-should-i-use-for-give-me-teh-codez) which is itself a duplicate of [What's the appropriate new/current close reason for “How do I do X?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/)

Comment: [Should I close “Does my code work?” questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289916/should-i-close-does-my-code-work-questions)

Comment: Pro tip (I didn't read the linked question): If you decide to answer (preferably along close and downvoting), give them an answer that doesn't really give them ready made code or solve the problem directly. Just give the necessary hints that still are valid answers. Be aware the question might be removed and any rep gained will be lost.

Comment: I always downvote, and vote to close as unclear.  As in, "That's a nice set of requirements you have there, bucko! But I'm a bit unclear as to what the problem you're having is.  Where's your code?  What's the error?  What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing, and what should it actually do?"