# I'm new at reviewing close votes. Do we have a guide for which option to choose?

Tags: support, close-reasons

So I've just started reviewing close votes, and I regularly come across a question  asking how to do something but not showing their code/attempts so far, or any sign of research beyond asking the question.

In this case, none of the options seem appropriate:

**too Broad** - nope, they're asking a specific question

**duplicate** - nope, it's a unique question

**unclear** - nope, I know what they're asking, they just haven't shown me what they've tried yet

**opinion-based** - nope, there's a clear correct answer (or several ways of doing it, perhaps)

**off-topic/seeking debugging help** - this seems the closest, but they're not really asking for debugging help, they're asking for the code itself.

People seem to vote "too broad" on these most often; and occasionally opinion-based.

Another example is when people are asking for code review, rather than issue resolution. There's no way to say "this belongs on code review", apart from leaving a comment; because code-review doesn't appear in the list of linked sites.

Is there a guide or some examples of how these things should be handled? It would be useful to have a page that says "you've got some new privileges! Congrats! Here's the ethos around using them...". I know we have this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions, which says the "how", but not the "when/why".

Or have I misunderstood the niche area of coding help that SO provides, and those types of questions are actually fine?

Comment: If no close-reason fits, you can either create a custom close reason... or not vote to close at all. If you have a hard time fitting the close reason, maybe it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: "Too broad" doesn't necessarily mean: "asks more than one question". The [help centre says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions): _" if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format"._ A "specific" question may have "too many valid answers".

Comment: And "how-to" questions, if adequately scoped, do not necessarily need to provide code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I close "Does my code work?" questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289916/should-i-close-does-my-code-work-questions)

Comment: When in doubt - "Skip"!

Comment: The closest thing I found are [these guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180032/392713), but admittedly they don't cover your special case.

Comment: The first description sounds like a "do my work for me" work order. They are often too broad, but in the rare cases that they're not... well then maybe you've found that exception which could just be answered and need not be closed. It's then up to quality voting to pass the final judgement.

Comment: For plenty "do my work" types of question, unclear is a good close reason, because you don't know what exactly is the problem for the OP.

Comment: You can always hit _off-topic_ and type in a custom close reason. Note that questions can be on-topic for both code review and Stack Overflow. The only real reasons we close questions on SO that are okay on Code Review is if they're too broad or opinion-based

Comment: Your interpretation of "Too-Board" isn't quite right.  Just because it is a specific question doesn't mean it isn't too board.  A lot of the "Do my work for me questions" actually fall into the too broad category and if they don't they usually fit the "unclear" close reason or don't need closed.   Too Broad isn't just whether the question is specific or not.  It could be a question in which you don't know where the person is stuck so you have to write a very broad reason to cover everything. Or a specific question that would require a novel to answer

Comment: The "guide" is the help center topics [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and the list of close reasons themselves. If they don't fit, you must acquit! I mean, Leave Open. Or at least Skip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right off the bat I see a little bit of a misunderstanding. The Close Vote Queue is not where you go to *review close votes (already cast by users)*. It's also not where you go to decide which close vote to apply to the questions within. It's where you go to review *questions* that have *already received* a vote or flag for closure. Critically, **you don't have to vote to close** the question there at all. You can, in fact, do any of the following actions:

- Vote to Leave Open - this choice adds 1 to the "leave open" tally for a given question. If a question receives 3 "Leave Open" votes, it will be removed from the queue.
- Edit - this choice lets you edit a question; it's useful for when you have identified problems that contributed in part or in whole to the question being considered close-worthy by someone. Editing a question from the queue will remove it from the queue.
- Skip - use this option if you aren't sure whether the question should be closed, stay open, or be edited. These don't count against you or your daily vote/review allotment, and aren't recorded in the system (publicly, at least. They're probably recorded *somewhere*). It literally just moves you to the next question in the queue.
- Vote to Close - this option you've already discovered. It's just the normal set of options you see when trying to close a question from the question page.

In your scenario #1, if a question seems to lack research effort but otherwise seems OK, then the proper action (if any) is a downvote, not a close vote. Downvotes are for lack of effort, lack of research, unclear questions, etc. Close votes are for things that are *off-topic*. The exception to lack of effort is homework questions; the community has decided that, while homework questions are on-topic, they must present an attempt at solving the problem (as we're not interested in doing someone's homework for them or enabling academic dishonesty).

In your scenario #2, if a question is asking for a code review or improvement, then look carefully. If they're asking for something that is **objectively answerable**, e.g. "how can this functionality be accomplished without the use of a lambda expression", that's OK. But if someone is asking something like "how can I make this better", or "how can this be written in a more Pythonic way" (or other language) or "is this the right way to go about doing this?" then the question is off-topic for the *Primarily Opinion-Based* reason; such questions can be answered a multitude of ways where "right" is based on opinions.

Comment: "The Close Vote Queue is not where you go to review close votes." This was a revelation to me and seems so simple that it could somehow be included somewhere in the workflow or permission description?

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate That'd probably be a good idea for all queues, but also probably as its own post (so that it gets proper attention).

Comment: "They're probably recorded *somewhere*" They definitely are, considering you can see them in [your history tab](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/history?skipped=true) if you check the box at the bottom.